# Chrome failed to open URL for protractor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor, ui-automation

below is error,

WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally

> > (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
> >     Command duration or timeout: 60.79 seconds
> >     Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
> >     System info: host: 'gdcckplt120490', ip: '3.209.35.158', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
> >     Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
> >         at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:580:13)
> >         at C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:64:13
> >         at Promise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1329:14)
> >         at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)
> >         at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)
> >         at C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2652:27
> >         at C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
> >         at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> >     From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
> >         at acquireSession (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:62:22)
> >         at Function.createSession (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:295:12)
> >         at Builder.build (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:458:24)
> >         at Local.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:37:33)
> >         at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:182:43)
> >         at C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:255:30
> >         at _fulfilled (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
> >         at C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
> >         at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
> >         at C:\Users\ylondhe\Documents\ProUI1\pd-operations-optimization-proui\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
> >     Warning: Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 1 Use --force to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 79 has been released recently so you need to get the latest drivers.
In your command line type
webdriver-manager update

Comment: After update command still throwing "WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally"

Comment: Can some one look into this issue pls?